# Cannot pass arguments from the tkinter widget.after function

Tags: python, popup, window, tkinter, arguments

Part of the GUI I'm building using tkinter has a pop-up window that says "Please wait while the program is running." then after it finishes the window goes away. I'm using the widget.after command to open the window and run the command. However if I pass the function I call arguments then the pop up window never occurs. Here's an example:

```
def backupWindow
    self.restoreCB = Toplevel()

    message = "Please wait while backup runs"
    Label(self.restoreCB, text=message, padx=100, pady=20).pack()

    widget.after(10, self.runBackup)

def runBackup(self):
    <backup code>
    self.backupCB.destroy()
```

This runs fine and does what I want it to do, the window pops up while the backup runs, then the window closes after the backup. However, If I pass the  and argument from the widget.after like the code below, the "please wait" message never shows up.

```
def backupWindow
    self.restoreCB = Toplevel()

    message = "Please wait while backup runs"
    Label(self.restoreCB, text=message, padx=100, pady=20).pack()

    widget.after(10, self.runBackup(mybackup))

def runBackup(self,mybackup):
    <backup code using mybackup>
    self.backupCB.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try functools.partial to wrap your call as in:

```
widget.after(10, functools.partial(self.runBackup, mybackup))
```

Or you could define a local function that takes no arguments but passes the parameter (which is in essence what functools.partial does).

Comment: While this is a perfectly acceptable solution, it's more complex than it needs to be. `after` is designed to take arguments, and use them when calling the function, the OP was just doing it wrong.

Comment: in this simple case you could just use a `lambda` to define an anonymous function instead of `functools.partial`: `widget.after(10, lambda: self.runBackup(mybackup))`

Answer (score 40):

When you do this:

```
widget.after(10, self.runBackup(mybackup))
```

... You are telling Tkinter "run the command `runBackup`, and when it returns, use the result as an argument to `after`". Because `runBackup` returns `None`, the above is equivalent to:

```
self.runBackup(mybackup)
widget.after(10, None)
```

Instead, you want to give `after` a *reference* to the function, rather than *calling* the function. If the command needs arguments, those can be given to `after` as additional arguments.

For example:

```
widget.after(10, self.runBackup, mybackup)
```

Comment: just for completeness, the resulting call is `widget.after(10, None)` because a function that has no return statement returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Add: Using Lambda function format, the function doesn´t fail after several recursive calls.
eg:

```
Function abc(par):
           stat-1
           stat-2
           ...
           stat-n
           root.after(1000, lambda : abc(par))

    ...
```

(it´s very useful to update a time-clock at left-top of window, for example...)

Comment: Do you mean that `.after(1000, lambda : abc(par))` is better for recursive calls than `.after(1000, abc, par)` ? Genuine question.