# Tkinter delay a copy command over ssh (Paramiko)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, paramiko

This script in Tkinter zip a file that reside in a linux server and then copy the zipped file in the local machine.
To do so, Paramiko first execute the zip command in the server, then a new function is called that copy the file in the local machine.
However, while the zip is being created, the new file gets a temporary name and only at the end of the zip procedure it gets the expected name (compressed_file.zip in the example). The file is large and the zipè procedure takes as much as ten seconds. The copy function return therefore an error of "IOError No such file" because the file is present but still with a temporary name.

I need to add a pause somehow, in a way that the copy function is delayed and allows the first to be completed.
I tried with **after** with no luck.  I can see from debugging that the copy_zip() is being executed without pausing for 10 seconds as I exepected.

(I cut all the logic that is not strictly needed to understand the problem)

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import paramiko
from tkFileDialog import * 
import os


root = Tk()
root.title("Extract file")
root.geometry('200x400+200+200')
root.resizable(width= FALSE, height= FALSE)


def copy_file():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    copy_command = ("zip compressed_file /log_folder/log.xml")
    client.connect(ip_server, username=user, password=psw)
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(copy_command)    
    root.after(10000, copy_zip())


def copy_zip():
    remotepath = "/home/user/compressed_file.zip"
    localpath = "c:\python27\copied_file.zip"
    t = paramiko.Transport(comboserver)
    t.connect(username=user, password=psw)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
    sftp.close

main_container = Frame(root, bg="bisque")
main_container.pack(side=TOP, fill="both", expand=False)

top_frame = LabelFrame(main_container, text =" Get File ")
top_frame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH)

t_go = Button(top_frame, text= "Go!", width =8, command = copy_file)
t_go.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 15, pady = 20)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Making some test with **after**, I discovered that it doesn't work if the function is called with an argument. In other words, I should call **root.after(10000, copy_zip)**. But what if I need to pass to the function some arguments (like I actually need to do)? I cannot pass any argument to the function if I use **after**?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `after` incorrectly. `after` must be given a *reference* to the function but you are *calling* the function and passing the result to *after*.

change your use of `after` to this:

```
root.after(10000, copy_zip)
```

If you want to pass arguments to `copy_file`, include them as arguments to `after`:

```
root.after(10000, copy_zip, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: Thank you, I just finished reading your answer here **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040098/cannot-pass-arguments-from-the-tkinter-widget-after-function** when I received the notification of your answer. I was able to find the usefull answer only when I realized that I was not able to pass argument to the function.