# Tkinter Canvas Update

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am building a script having one counter and an image. Both are in different canvas on single window. I am trying to update the canvas image once the timer stops. Below is my code. I am not getting whats wrong with this

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import stopwatch
import stone_image


class App():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.configure(background="yellow")

        global stoneImagePanel

        stopwatchPanel = tk.Canvas(self.root, background="yellow")
        stoneImagePanel = tk.Canvas(self.root, background="yellow")

        stopwatchPanel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="e")
        stoneImagePanel.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=4, sticky="news")


        self.stoneImage_canvas(stoneImagePanel)
        self.stopWatch_canvas(stopwatchPanel)


    def stopWatch_canvas(self, parent):
        stopwatch.timerStart(parent, 500)
        stoneImagePanel.after(500, self.update(stoneImagePanel))

    def stoneImage_canvas (self, parent):
        displayImage = stone_image.DisplayImage(parent)
        displayImage.stoneImg('images/stone.jpg')

    def update(self, parent):
        displayImage = stone_image.DisplayImage(parent)
        displayImage.stoneImg('images/UP.png')



if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Neither the stopwatch is working smoothly nor the image is updating. Please help.

Comment: At least 1 of your problems is the way you add an argument to the callback in your `.after()` method. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11042380/4084269

Comment: Yes.. I have tried it but no luck

Comment: When I am trying to destroy the stoneImagePanel, even then its not working