# tkinter after calling function with parameters causing function to hang

Tags: python, tkinter

This is for a game of life app and using after to slow the animation of cells through the stages of birth, life, death, etc.

Couple issues with after:

1.I've been researching Tkinter extensively and this post captures the most clear instructions I have found [regarding after with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040098/cannot-pass-arguments-from-the-tkinter-widget-after-function), however, my application of Tkinter is not working - based on comments already received it's probably not the after but that's where the symptoms are appearing? 
2.Basically the after does not appear to work at all when I don't put the parameters into parentheses inside the after (ex. widget.after(200, self.my_function, parameter 1, parameter 2, ....) doesn't iterate. However, when I do the same but enclose the parameters it iterates as intended (ex. widget.after(200, self.my_function(parameter 1, parameter 2, ....)).

3.However, when run with the parameters in parentheses, the after hangs. The list in the code below contains 81 items and not coincidentally, the function hangs for 16.2 seconds...

Code is as follows:

```
 def color_cells(
           self, 
           cells, 
           repeater, 
           temp_cells=0, 
           counter=0, 
           after_id=None
           ):

    global paused

    if temp_cells != 0:

        self.repeat_colors(temp_cells)
        temp_cells.clear()
        temp_cells = 0
        for key in cells:
            if cells[key][0] == 'emerging':
                cells[key] = 'active', colors['active'][1]
            if cells[key][0] == 'dying':
                cells[key] = 'inactive', colors['inactive'][1]
        counter = 0
        if repeater and not paused:
            print("repeater is ", repeater, " and paused is ",paused)
            self.id_changes(cells)
        else:
            self.closeoutGame()

    else:

    try:
       print("made it to the else in color_cells and repeater is ",repeater, " and length of temp cells list is ", len(temp_cells))

    except:
       print("made it to the else in color_cells and repeater is ",repeater, " and temp cells is empty")

        for key in cells:
            color_rectangle = self.canvas_manager.find_withtag(key)
            self.canvas_manager.itemconfigure(color_rectangle, fill = cells[key][1])
            self.canvas_manager.update()



def repeat_colors(self, temp_cells, counter=0):
    print("starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is ", len(temp_cells), " and the counter is ",counter)
    if counter < len(temp_cells):
        color_rectangle = self.canvas_manager.find_withtag(temp_cells[counter][0])
        self.canvas_manager.itemconfigure(color_rectangle, fill = temp_cells[counter][1])
        self.canvas_manager.update()
        counter = counter + 1
        root.after(200, self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, counter))
```

Bryan, you had asked for an example of the error. To show the error I added some print statements to the calling function and then explained where the 16.2 second period of inactivity starts:

```
 starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is  81  and the counter is  0
 starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is  81  and the counter is  1
 starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is  81  and the counter is  2
 ...
 starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is  81  and the counter is  79
 starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is  81  and the counter is  80
 starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is  81  and the counter is  81

 ...hangs for the 16.2 seconds, equal to 200 ms x 81 iterations
```

I'm a hobbyist and have no formal training and so I'm sure I'm overlooking something basic here, including how to best research on my own. But I appreciate any advice.

Comment: You need to convert your after to pass a lambda. Change this: `root.after(200, self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, counter))` to this: `root.after(200, lambda x=counter: self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, x))`

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `after(200, self.my_funciton, parameter 1, ...)` doesn't work. There's absolutely no reason why it wouldn't work, and is the preferred solution. Can you please provide a [mcve] that shows it not working?

Comment: @BryanOakley - added more code and an example.

Comment: Your edits don't show using the correct form of `after`.

Comment: Edited the code sample to insert the print statement that produced the text in the error example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest neither:

```
root.after(200, self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, counter))
```

nor:

```
root.after(200, lambda x=counter: self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, x))
```

but rather:

```
root.after(200, self.repeat_colors, temp_cells, counter)
```

This is a misunderstanding of `after()` I see often and had myself.  The definition of `after()`:

> after(ms, func=None, *args)
>
> ```
> Call function once after given time.
>
> MS specifies the time in milliseconds. FUNC gives the
> function which shall be called. Additional parameters
> are given as parameters to the function call.  Return
> identifier to cancel scheduling with after_cancel.
> ```

The code you posted with the above fix and other tweaking -- unfortunately hard to do well without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
def color_cells(self, cells, repeater, temp_cells=None, counter=0):

    if temp_cells is not None:

        self.repeat_colors(temp_cells)
        temp_cells.clear()
        temp_cells = None

        for key in cells:
            if cells[key][0] == 'emerging':
                cells[key] = 'active', colors['active'][1]
            if cells[key][0] == 'dying':
                cells[key] = 'inactive', colors['inactive'][1]

        counter = 0

        if repeater and not paused:
            print("repeater is", repeater, "and paused is", paused)
            self.id_changes(cells)
        else:
            self.closeoutGame()
    else:
        print("Made it to the else in color_cells and repeater is", repeater, "and temp cells is empty")

        for key in cells:
            color_rectangle = self.canvas_manager.find_withtag(key)
            self.canvas_manager.itemconfigure(color_rectangle, fill=cells[key][1])
            self.canvas_manager.update()

def repeat_colors(self, temp_cells, counter=0):
    print("Starting repeat colors and the temps cells len is", len(temp_cells), "and the counter is", counter)

    if counter < len(temp_cells):
        color_rectangle = self.canvas_manager.find_withtag(temp_cells[counter][0])
        self.canvas_manager.itemconfigure(color_rectangle, fill=temp_cells[counter][1])
        self.canvas_manager.update()
        counter += 1
        root.after(200, self.repeat_colors, temp_cells, counter)
```

Comment: Thank you @cdlane. I tweaked per the above but it is still not working. However, I completely agree with the revisions to the after(). I think there is another error elsewhere that is throwing the after off. Still working on that.

Answer (score 1):

You problem would be the infinite loop caused by `root.after(200, self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, counter))`. Instead you need to pass your `self.repeat_colors` as a lambda.

So what is happening is the `self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, counter)` is being called instantly instead of waiting the 200 seconds. So instead create a lambda function that will wait until the set time to activate.

Keep in mind for lambda expressions if you have a value that changes you need to define it in the lambda. So for the counter you need to do something like `x=counter` so the lambda is sure to use the correct updated value instead. This normally affects things like loops that create lambda expressions and probably does not matter in this particular case but is a good habit to practice for when it does matter.

Change this:

```
root.after(200, self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, counter))
```

To this:

```
root.after(200, lambda x=counter: self.repeat_colors(temp_cells, x))
```

Comment: Sure hope that *infant* loop didn't quit prematurely... :)

Comment: @Mike-SMT I made the suggested change, but, had the same affect as running it without parentheses. Starting to wonder if there is broader issue that the after is just bringing to light. I also added code and an example of the error. Thanks!